# storing and retrieving a value in metro apps?

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a metro application in which I have Login-Page where am entering values for username and password fields.Based on these values my application will need to call web-services.Can anyone give me advice to store and retrieve the values from Login-Page?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you struggling with?  What have you tried?  What worked and what didn't?  You need to give us more information about these things before we can help.

Comment: Actually I want to store username and password from Login-Page and I need use those values in my entire application?

Comment: A) Grab the items from the form elements using getElementById
b) use the Jeff Brand response below to persist the creds between sessions.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [CredentialPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.ui.credentialpicker.aspx) class. See https://gist.github.com/3790578 for a full example using the CredentialPicker and then storing it in the PasswordVault.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the PasswordVault API.  Check out the sample app... Credential locker sample @  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PasswordVault-f01be74a and read up on the PasswordVault class @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx